# Ember-cli: Inject version into app

Tags: node.js, ember-cli

I like to display my project version (from package.json), the git commit hash and working-copy status in the footer of my Ember app built using ember-cli and broccoli.

I can grab the version prefix easily enough by adding to my config/environment.js:

```
ENV.APP.version = require('../package.json').version
```

I was using grunt-git-describe previously to grab the revision hash and dirty/clean status. How can I do something similar in ember-cli?

Simply shelling out to `git describe` is problematic since child_process does not have a synchronous method of executing a shell command.

It there a way I can return a promise from somewhere and prevent config/environment.js from resolving until my async `git describe` completes?

The npm packages exec-sync and execSync don't seem to work well for me on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ember-git-version](https://www.npmjs.org/package/ember-git-version) is an ember-cli addon that provides the current revision hash.

After installing the node package, the config/environment hash will have a property `currentRevision`. See [initializers/print-git-info.js](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-git-version/blob/master/app/initializers/print-git-info.js) for how to access it from your app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `exec-sync` package and then add something like this to Brocfile.js:

```
var execSync = require('exec-sync'),
    gitVersion = execSync('git describe');

fs.writeFileSync('app/version.js', 'App.version = "' + gitVersion + '";';
```

You'll then need to import that somewhere.

Comment: Unfortunately exec-sync doesn't seem to work on Windows when I tried it.